# Prevent child nodes from 'popping' on page load (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following D3 code for showing this visual:

[image: Force Directed Graph]

The children (words) after the yellow nodes 'pop' out when the page loads.  But I would only like the visual to show the yellow nodes when the page loads and show the words only when the user clicks on the yellow node. Currently you can collapse and 'pop' the yellow nodes by clicking on them which is perfect...I just dont want the yellow nodes to show the words on page load.

```
    < script type = "text/javascript" >

    var w = 1100,
        h = 600,
        node,
        path,
        root, nodes, links, rootNode, id = 19;

var force, vis;
var LoadData = true;


function update() {
    if (force) force.stop();
    nodes = flatten(root);
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    // Restart the force layout.
    force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .linkDistance(100)
        .charge(-1500)
        .theta(1)
        .gravity(0.03)
        .start();


    vis.selectAll("path").remove();
    vis.selectAll(".node").remove();

    path = vis.selectAll("path.link");
    path = path.data(force.links());
    path.exit().remove();
    path
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

    node = vis.selectAll(".node");
    node = node.data(force.nodes());
    node.exit().remove();
    node
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", click)
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
            return d.imageURL;
        }) //http://t2.gstatic.//com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6fN48PEP2-z-JbutdhqfypsYdciYTAZEziHpBJZLAfM6rxqYX";})
        .attr("class", "image")
        .attr("x", -20)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("width", 42)
        .attr("height", 42);

    node.append("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .attr("x", 15)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("fill", color)
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        });
}



function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {

        if (d.source.id == rootNode.id) {
            d.source.x = (w / 2 - 15);
            d.source.y = (h / 2 - 15);
        }

        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" +
            d.source.x + "," +
            d.source.y + "A" +
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
            d.target.x + "," +
            d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {

        if (d.id == rootNode.id) {
            return "translate(" + ((w / 2) - 20) + "," + ((h / 2) - 20) + ")";
        }
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

}

function color(d) {
    return d._children ? "#778899" : d.children ? "#778899" : "#778899";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {

    if ((d.children != null || d.children != undefined) || (d._children != null || d._children != undefined)) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update();
    }

}


var findNode = function(node) {
    for (var i in force.nodes()) {
        if (force.nodes()[i] === node) return true
    };
    return false;
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [],
        i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }

    rootNode = root;
    recurse(root);

    return nodes;
}


function loadImage() {
    if (LoadData) {

        force = d3.layout.force()
            .on("tick", tick)
            .size([w, h]);

        vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
        update();
        LoadData = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `nodes.forEach(function(d) { d._children = d.children; d.children = null; })`

Comment: where do you see this going

Comment: That would be easier to answer if we could tell how to get this started. Where is `root` set? I tried pasting this into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/c8h85g7y/), but the first call to `flatten` fails because `root` is undefined.

Comment: It is set by calling in flare.json using ajax as: $.getJSON(data_path, function(data) {root = data});

Comment: @Cybernetic run this after setting `nodes` and before calling `update()` (you need to set `nodes` external to the function for this).

Comment: @Lars The closest I can get is putting your line into the flatten(root) function...this only shows the yellow nodes which is great....but now they don't expand into words when you click on them.

Comment: Yes, that's why you should run it only once. This is modifying the internal data structures so that everything is closed.